# load_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Been following a few guides on Tensorflow and Keras, new to python, came from c++. Having an issue saying "load_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath'"

heres my code:

```
from keras.datasets import cifar10
import keras.utils as utils
from keras.models import load_model
import numpy as np

labelsArray = ["airplane","automobile","bird","cat","deer","dog","frog","horse","ship","truck"]

(_, _), (testImages, testLabels) = cifar10.load_data()

testImages = testImages.astype('float32') / 255.0
testLabels = utils.to_categorical(testLabels)

model = load_model(filepath='Image_Classifier.h5')

results = model.evaluate(x=testImages, y=testLabels)
print("Train loss:", results[0])
print("Test Accuracy:", results[1])
```

Comment: I dont see any problem with the code, since you supplied `filepath` to `load_model`

Comment: try without keyword `load_model('Image_Classifier.h5')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** The fix is to not specify the filepath as a keyword parameter:

```
model = load_model('Image_Classifier.h5')
```

#### Longer Explanation:

I think the reason is that `filepath` is being treated as a positional argument instead of a keyword argument (see the `parameter` entry in [the glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html) for explanations of these). If you look at the [`load_model`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/1cf5218edb23e575a827ca4d849f1d52d21b4bb0/keras/engine/saving.py#L552) function itself this is confusing, because the signature is:

```
def load_model(filepath, custom_objects=None, compile=True)
```

Here `filepath` is a positional-or-keyword argument - you can either just pass the filename in the first position or do what you did and say `filepath='Image_Classifier.h5'`. BUT, there is some more machinery in place that complicates it. The error I receive when I run your code is

```
    model = load_model(filepath='Image_Classifier.h5')
File "/Users/adam/.miniconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 492, in load_wrapper
    return load_function(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: load_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath'
```

Note the `load_model` function is not being called directly, it is going through this [`load_wrapper`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/1cf5218edb23e575a827ca4d849f1d52d21b4bb0/keras/engine/saving.py#L479) function with signature

```
def load_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
```

The function signature allows for an arbitrary number of positional arguments followed by an arbitrary number of keyword arguments. That function then seems to do some processing of what was passed in to find keyword args, and my guess is if you pass `filepath` as a keyword parameter, it then doesn't have anything to pass for `*args`, even though the `load_model` function expects exactly one thing to be passed through the positional `*args`.

The end result is `filepath` gets treated as a positional-only argument, and you must pass the value directly without specifying it as a keyword argument.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message

> load_model() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filepath'

gives you a good indication of the problem - "missing 1 required **positional** argument". This means that the `filepath` should not be passed as a keyword argument as you have done in your code. Instead, you can call [`load_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model) like:

```
model = load_model('Image_Classifier.h5')
```